# creating an HTML5 piano roll editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am creating a piano roll like interface, one like you might find in a DAW such as ableton, that looks something like this http://www.abletonlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/midi-track-big.jpg . The grid represents a canvas to draw in notes to be played, the red squares being the notes to play. You double click on an empty space to create a new note, and you can drag the edges to change the length of the note.

I am new to web dev so I am having a bit of trouble seeing what the right architecture for this might be. With my limited knowledge, the following are the architectures I can think of.

1) Rows of horizontal flex-boxes.

```
display: box;
box-orient: horizontal;
box-flex: 1;
```

Something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/ZgzNw/.

Pros:

- When resizing the browser window, the browser will automatically
  handle resizing of the notes and therefore the grid. Resizing of divs/notes also handled easily for zooming in and out and changing quantization values.
- All notes in all positions already exist, when double clicking to "create" a new note, all you have to do is change the css for that note (to be red) etc.

Cons:

- Since there is a div for every space in the grid, even empty spaces where there is no note to be played, there will be a lot of divs. Can the browser handle thousands of divs? As an extreme example if there is a 32nd note quantization, a song of 200BPM would have 50 measures per minute, take a 10 minutes song, that would be 500 measures. Going back to the jsfiddle example above and setting measures=500 and quant=32, I get the following error in the Chrome Developer tools console after a few seconds "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". This is when creating the divs in that bit of javascript, If I lower the number to around 300 it is able to create the divs, but things become laggy.

2) Create the grid using divs of width=1px for the vertical lines of the grid. Create new note divs on the fly, position them manually (with position: float?) based on the position of the mouse click.

Pros:

- Only have a divs for actual note that are on, so don't have the con of method 1) being an issue

Cons:

- Have to manually compute everything, Where to place newly created note, zooming in/out means repositioning vertical markers for grids, and calculating new sizes for note divs. This was mostly handled automatically in the method 1.

I'm sure there are a lot more architectures and pros/cons to the two methods I describe, but I've never created any web applications and the extent of my web-dev experience is the tutorials I've done over the last 2 weeks to teach myself.

My question I guess is what is the best architecture for creating this piano roll interface I am describing? Specifically the UI representation, not the backing model.

Comment: This sounds like something you'd actually be better off using a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) for. Computation on-the-fly is the only way to go. "Can the browser handle thousands of divs?" Yes, but it won't be happy about it, each `<div>` has a lot of information stored with it, would eat up lots of memory and then CPU as the page is computed & rendered.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't go with the first example. As using music software and so pianorolls a lot (mostly Ableton Live and Maschine) I would expect to see a longer part in the viewport, when I resize the window. So lets say I see four bars on a browser width of 400px I would expect to see 5 bars on 500px. So I would put a zooming feature (horizontally and vertically) separate and not relative to the viewport size.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, actually in Ableton Live you see a fixed number of bars/time when resizing the window, you have to zoom in/out to see more time/bars. Regardless, either functionality when resizing the window could be implemented with the first method, I'm more interested in pros/cons of the high level architecture.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I said. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would create a simple model (probably just a multi-dimensional array) to contain the representation of the score, where each array item represented a note at a point in time. From the model, you can then draw/redraw accordingly. You could also perform operations like time shifts, quantizing, thinning, etc. by modifying the arrays.

> Can the browser handle thousands of divs?

A few thousand, yes, maybe more--maybe even a lot more--but results will greatly vary by browser, by computer, even by the way they are positioned (floats tend to be slower than absolute positioning, for example, because the browser has more to calculate).

Instead, I would research using a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) and draw/redraw based on your underlying model. You can detect events on the whole canvas, and depending on coordinates, easily map the event to the note(s) to which it corresponds.

[KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) has some cool examples using a canvas

Comment: I always thought canvas is for more specialized UIs. My layout is relatively simple, a bunch of resizable/movable rectangles. Can you help me better understand what would be the advantage of using canvas in this case over just divs that are positioned. With my limited knowledge I can only see disadvantages to using canvas in this scenario: have to handle mapping clicks/events based on mouse position manually vs just attaching a onclick handler to a div, easy resizing of div (jquery-ui resizable). When zooming in/out it seems both would require computation of new size (vs method 1).

Comment: That's a valid opinion, though I would argue that this is a somewhat specialized UI. Performance is a strong argument for manual drawing. Flexibility is another; you can draw *anything* you want on a canvas; while there are tons of options with HTML elements (like a DIV) there still are limits.

Comment: If you want to go the element route (the DIVs), I would still definitely create a simple model to represent the data. Perhaps you can only draw a portion of the model at one time (and remove hidden nodes), which would make performance acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a background image to represent tracks and measures, and one div for each note. It is not necessary to keep all notes as div’s in the browser, it would work better only to have the div’s for the visible up to 10 measures.

Imho, this should be done fixed-width, and there should not be any resizing of the piano roll at all. So you can use calculation of pixels. I don’t think this will work without making use of Javascript heavily.